# How to sort records runtime based on time slot?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code which is working fine for me.
For demo purposes, I'm adding only a few records into the list in real time this list is continuously added with new values per second.
question is how to sort that realtime data based on time slot?
Hosted below code into continuously running webjob.

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }

    public DateTime GetStartOfPeriodByMins(int numMinutes) 
    {
        int oldMinutes = Time.Minute;
        int newMinutes = (oldMinutes / numMinutes) * numMinutes;

        DateTime startOfPeriod = new DateTime(Time.Year, Time.Month, Time.Day, Time.Hour, newMinutes, 0);

        return startOfPeriod;
    }
}


List<MyObject> inputList = new List<MyObject>();

inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 0), Value = 12});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 2), Value = 11});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 5), Value = 13});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 15), Value = 14});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 45), Value = 12});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 55), Value = 11});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 16, 0), Value = 13});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 16, 1), Value = 16});


var resultSet = inputList
    .GroupBy(i => i.GetStartOfPeriodByMins(1))
    .Select(gr =>
        new 
        {
            StartOfPeriod = gr.Key,
            Min = gr.Min(item => item.Value),
            Max = gr.Max(item => item.Value),
            Open = gr.OrderBy(item => item.Time).First().Value,
            Close = gr.OrderBy(item => item.Time).Last().Value
        });

var my = resultSet.ToList();
```

The time slot taken here is 1 minute so for every minute it will give me separate values of that minutes open high low and close.

[image]

I want to process data from `inputList` so that after every 1 minute I will get the latest dataset of the recent 1 minute so that I can use it for further calculation.

Comment: who has mark it closed without giving any inputs :( try to give some code snippet which i can tryout. These types of questions are very tricky and useful to many users.

Comment: I'd guess someone marked this for closure since it's not clear what you're asking here. What exactly does it mean that "inputList will get continuous new data from API"?

Comment: Oh ok I have hosted this code into azure webjob so api is websocket api which is continuously giving me tickee data which I'm adding into inputlist... Pls guide how to sort that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is continues inserts (add), you can use SortedSet instead on List.

```
public class MyObjectComparer : IComparer<MyObject>
{
    public int Compare(MyObject x, MyObject y)
    {
        return x.Time.CompareTo(y.Time);
    }
}

var inputList = new SortedSet<MyObject>(new MyObjectComparer());

inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 0), Value = 12});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 2), Value = 11});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 5), Value = 13});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 15), Value = 14});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 45), Value = 12});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 15, 55), Value = 11});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 16, 0), Value = 13});
Thread.Sleep(1000);
inputList.Add(new MyObject() {Time = new DateTime(2020, 10, 10, 9, 16, 1), Value = 16});
```

So for each add, the set (list) will be in correct order.

```
public class MyObject 
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    
    public DateTime Created { get; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime Ttl { get; } = DateTime.Now.AddMinues(5);
    public DateTime? Persisted { get; set; }

    public bool IsDead => DateTime.Now > Ttl;
    public bool IsPersisted => Persisted.HasValue;
    public bool TimeToPersist => IsPersisted == false && DateTime.Now > Create.AddMinutes(2);

    public DateTime GetStartOfPeriodByMins(int numMinutes) 
    {
        int oldMinutes = Time.Minute;
        int newMinutes = (oldMinutes / numMinutes) * numMinutes;

        DateTime startOfPeriod = new DateTime(Time.Year, Time.Month, Time.Day, Time.Hour, newMinutes, 0);

        return startOfPeriod;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks... is there any way to only persist data of current 1minutes or 5 minute in a new list and after a 1 or 5 minute it will clear old data?

Comment: no, you have make your own Persisted and TTL (Time To Live) state for that.

Comment: Ok I think I need to create a new list where I can maintain latest 1 minutes or 5 minutes data from Inputlist. Right? Any sample code snippet you can think of I will also try from my end like using MemoryCache thanks

Comment: I have updated the answer with some properties on `MyObject` that should support your request. Ajust the minutes....

Comment: after implementation above code still im getting same number of records after execution :( idea we have used TTL so we should get last minutes record only i will investigate more. thank you

Comment: You have to run though the list "manually" and remove those `IsDead == true`, same goes for those that must be persisted.